# How to get the coefficients of second-order Runge-Kutta formula coherently?

Tags: numerics

The form of the second order Runge Kutta formula is as follows(the following is from page 287 of [this book](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000006641172&d=CB6E1ED34FB8B2B0879DD74D4A4AA569&fenlei=130116)):

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y_{n+1}=y_{n}+h\left(c_{1} K_{1}+c_{2} K_{2}\right) \\
K_{1}=f\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right) \\
K_{2}=f\left(x_{n}+\lambda_{2} h, y_{n}+\mu_{21} h K_{1}\right)
\end{array}\right.$$

Its truncation error is: $T_{n+1}=y\left(x_{n+1}\right)-y\left(x_{n}\right)-h\left[c_{1} f\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)+c_{2} f\left(x_{n}+\lambda_{2} h, y_{n}+\mu_{21} h f_{n}\right)\right]$, where $y\left(x_{n+1}\right)=y_{n}+h y_{n}^{\prime}+\frac{h^{2}}{2} y_{n}^{\prime \prime}+\frac{h^{3}}{3 !} y_{n}^{\prime \prime \prime}+O\left(h^{4}\right)$.

And we know the following relationship:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y_{n}^{\prime}=f\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)=f_{n} \\
y_{n}^{\prime \prime}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} f\left(x_{n}, y\left(x_{n}\right)\right)=f_{x}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)+f_{y}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right) f_{n} \\
y_{n}^{\prime \prime \prime}=f_{x x}^{\prime \prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)+2 f_{n} f_{x y}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)+f_{n}^{2} f_{y y}^{\prime \prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right) \\
\quad+f_{y}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)\left[f_{x}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)+f_{n} f_{y}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)\right] \\
f\left(x_{n}+\lambda_{2} h, y_{n}+\mu_{21} h f_{n}\right)=f_{n}+f_{x}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right) \lambda_{2} h+f_{y}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right) \mu_{21} h f_{n}+O\left(h^{2}\right)
\end{array}\right.$$

By introducing the above relation into the truncation error expression, we can obtain :

$$\begin{aligned}
T_{n+1}=& h f_{n}+\frac{h^{2}}{2}\left[f_{x}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)+f_{y}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right) f_{n}\right] \\
&-h\left[c_{1} f_{n}+c_{2}\left(f_{n}+\lambda_{2} f_{x}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right) h\right.\right.\\
&\left.\left.+\mu_{21} f_{y}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right) f_{n} h\right)\right]+O\left(h^{3}\right) \\
=&\left(1-c_{1}-c_{2}\right) f_{n} h+\left(\frac{1}{2}-c_{2} \lambda_{2}\right) f_{x}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right) h^{2} \\
&+\left(\frac{1}{2}-c_{2} \mu_{21}\right) f_{y}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right) f_{n} h^{2}+O\left(h^{3}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

If the above truncation error has second-order accuracy, the following relations should be satisfied:

$$1-c_{1}-c_{2}=0, \quad \frac{1}{2}-c_{2} \lambda_{2}=0, \quad \frac{1}{2}-c_{2} \mu_{21}=0$$

If $a=1, c_{2}=1, c_{1}=0, \lambda_{2}=\mu_{21}=1 / 2$, a second-order Runge Kutta formula is obtained:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y_{n+1}=y_{n}+h K_{2} \\
K_{1}=f\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right) \\
K_{2}=f\left(x_{n}+\frac{h}{2}, y_{n}+\frac{h}{2} K_{1}\right)
\end{array}\right.$$

I want to use MMA to reproduce the process smoothly.

```
(Series[y[s], {s, tn, 3}] // Normal) /. s -> tn + h

((f[x[n], y[x[n]]] - f[x[n], y[x[n]]] + h*f[x[n], y[x[n]]] + 
       h^2/2 D[f[x[n], y[x[n]]], x[n]] - 
       h (c1*f[x[n], y[x[n]]] + 
           c2*((Series[
                 f[x[n] + h1, y[x[n]] + h2], {h1, 0, 1}, {h2, 0, 1}] //
                 Normal) /. {h1 :> λ2*h, 
               h2 :> μ21*h*f[x[n], y[x[n]]]}) // 
          ExpandAll)) /. {a -> 1, c2 -> 1, 
      c1 -> 0, λ2 -> 1/2, μ21 -> 1/2}) /. 
   Derivative[1][y][x[n]] -> f[x[n], y[x[n]]] // 
  FullSimplify // Expand

SolveAlways[(((f[x[n], y[x[n]]] - f[x[n], y[x[n]]] + 
   h*f[x[n], y[x[n]]] + h^2/2 D[f[x[n], y[x[n]]], x[n]] - 
   h (c1*f[x[n], y[x[n]]] + 
       c2*((Series[
             f[x[n] + h1, y[x[n]] + h2], {h1, 0, 1}, {h2, 0, 1}] //
             Normal) /. {h1 :> λ2*h, 
           h2 :> μ21*h*f[x[n], y[x[n]]]}) // ExpandAll))) /. 
Derivative[1][y][x[n]] -> f[x[n], y[x[n]]]) == 0, h]
```

But the code is not coherent enough to get the desired results. **What should I do to solve this problem according to the idea of the textbook?**

**It is extended to the third-order Runge Kutta formula:**

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y_{n+1}=y_{n}+\frac{h}{6}\left(K_{1}+4 K_{2}+K_{3}\right) \\
K_{1}=f\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right) \\
K_{2}=f\left(x_{n}+\frac{h}{2}, y_{n}+\frac{h}{2} K_{1}\right) \\
K_{3}=f\left(x_{n}+h, y_{n}-h K_{1}+2 h K_{2}\right)
\end{array}\right.$$

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"]
    K1 = f[x[n], y[x[n]]];
    K2 = ((Series[f[x[n] + h1, y[x[n]] + h2], {h1, 0, 2}, {h2, 0, 2}] // 
          Normal) /. {h1 :> λ2*h, 
         h2 :> μ21*h*f[x[n], y[x[n]]]});
    K3 = ((Series[f[x[n] + h1, y[x[n]] + h2], {h1, 0, 2}, {h2, 0, 2}] // 
            Normal) /. {h1 :> λ3*h, 
           h2 :> μ31*h*f[x[n], y[x[n]]] + μ32*h*(K2)} // 
         ExpandAll) /. h^a_ /; a > 4 :> 0;
    ((f[x[n], y[x[n]]] - f[x[n], y[x[n]]] + h*f[x[n], y[x[n]]] + 
            h^2/2 D[f[x[n], y[x[n]]], x[n]] + 
            h^3/3! D[f[x[n], y[x[n]]], x[n], x[n]] + 
            h^4/4! D[f[x[n], y[x[n]]], x[n], x[n], x[n]] - 
            h (c1*(K1) + c2*(K2) + c3*(K3)) /. {c1 -> 1/6, c2 -> 4/6, 
            c3 -> 1/6, λ2 -> 1/2, μ21 -> 1/2, λ3 -> 
             1, μ31 -> -1, μ32 -> 2}) //. {Derivative[1][y][
            x[n]] :> f[x[n], y[x[n]]], 
          Derivative[2][y][x[n]] :> D[f[x[n], y[x[n]]], x[n]], 
          Derivative[3][y][x[n]] :> D[f[x[n], y[x[n]]], x[n], x[n]]} // 
        FullSimplify // Expand) /. h^a_ /; a > 4 :> 0(*the result shows that the lowest degree of polynomial about h is 4*)
```

**Multistep linear method:**

```
y[x[n + i]] = (Series[y[s], {s, x[n], 3}] // Normal) /. s -> x[n] + i*h
y'[x[n + i]] = (Series[y'[s], {s, x[n], 3}] // Normal) /. 
  s -> x[n] + i*h

k = 3; 
Collect[Expand[
     Evaluate[Normal[Series[y[s], {s, x[n], 3}]] /. 
           s -> x[n] + k*h] - 
       Sum[Evaluate[α[i]*y[x[n + i]]], {i, 0, k - 1}] - 
       h*Sum[Evaluate[β[i]*Derivative[1][y][x[n + i]]], 
           {i, 0, k}]], {h, Derivative[_][y][_], y[_]}]

sol = FindInstance[-α[0] - α[1] - α[2] + 1 == 
    0 && -α[1] - 
     2 α[2] - β[0] - β[1] - β[2] - β[
      3] + 3 == 
    0 && -(α[1]/2) - 2 α[2] - β[1] - 
     2 β[2] - 3 β[3] + 9/2 == 
    0 && -(α[1]/6) - (4 α[2])/3 - β[1]/2 - 
     2 β[2] - (9 β[3])/2 + 9/2 == 0, {α[
    0], α[1], α[2], β[0], β[1], β[
    2], β[3]}]

y[n + k] == Sum[α[i]*y[n + i], {i, 0, k - 1}] + 
       h*Sum[β[i]*f[n + i], {i, 0, k}] /. First[sol]
```